# how to solve pubspec.yaml error? After trying every solution from YouTube?

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, pubspec.yaml

Why isn't this code running?

why is it displaying (pubspec.yaml  1,M) ?

And it's showing rethrow with symbol?

I tried every solution on YouTube, but this error still persists.
After saving and running the code, it displays rethrow with some symbol.
After doing Restart still its showing same error.

I want to add image in flutter(Vscode)?
Is there another way to add an image in Flutter?

[Showing (pubspec.yaml 1,M)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFrzW.png)

[After running this. Its showing rethrow with some symbol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUi3C.png)

Answer (score 3):

You need to create `assets` folder on  project root level. And then inside it, create another folder `images`

It will be look like this

[image]

Then put your assets images there.

Find more about  [assets-and-images](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/assets-and-images)